# How To Paginate SQL Server Rows When Using GROUP BY and Aggregates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pagination

I am trying to paginate SQL Server rows. I have found a few tutorials online, but I am failing to grasp every detail, which is causing me to fail miserably at adapting [their examples](http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2012-introduction-pagination/) to my existing query.

**The Tutorial's Instructions:**

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2
GO
SELECT
  m.RowNr,
  m.SalesOrderID,
  m.SalesOrderDetailID,
  m.OrderQty,
  m.ProductID,
  m.UnitPrice,
  m.LineTotal,
  m.rowguid,
  m.ModifiedDate
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SalesOrderDetailID DESC) AS RowNr,
      SalesOrderID,
      SalesOrderDetailID,
      OrderQty,
      ProductID,
      UnitPrice,
      LineTotal,
      rowguid,
      ModifiedDate
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS tbl
  )m
WHERE RowNr BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

**My Existing (Non-Paginated) Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  MAX(i.ID) AS ID,
  i.ItemLookupCode,
  MAX(CAST(i.Notes AS varchar(max))) AS Notes,
  MAX(CONVERT(varchar(30), i.Price, 1)) AS Price,
  MAX(i.PictureName) AS PictureName

FROM Item AS i

LEFT JOIN nitroasl_pamtable AS n
  ON i.ID = n.ItemID

WHERE ( i.ID LIKE '%hdmi%' OR i.ItemLookupCode LIKE '%hdmi%' OR i.Notes LIKE '%hdmi%' OR i.Description LIKE '%hdmi%' OR i.ExtendedDescription LIKE '%hdmi%' OR n.ManufacturerPartNumber LIKE '%hdmi%' OR n.PAM_Keywords LIKE '%hdmi%' )
AND ( i.WebItem = 0 AND i.Price > 0 )

GROUP BY i.ItemLookupCode

ORDER BY i.ItemLookupCode ASC;
```

**My Attempt**

```
/* Return Page */
SELECT
  i.RowID,
  MAX(i.ID) AS ID,
  i.ItemLookupCode,
  MAX(CAST(i.Notes AS varchar(max))) AS Notes,
  MAX(CONVERT(varchar(30), i.Price, 1)) AS Price,
  MAX(i.PictureName) AS PictureName
FROM (
  SELECT

    /* The following row is the line that is being blamed by the error */
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemLookupCode) AS RowID,

    MAX(ID) AS ID,
    ItemLookupCode,
    MAX(CAST(Notes AS varchar(max))) AS Notes,
    MAX(CONVERT(varchar(30), Price, 1)) AS Price,
    MAX(PictureName) AS PictureName
  FROM Item AS tbl
) AS i

WHERE RowID BETWEEN 1 AND 15;
```

The above query returns the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Column 'Item.ItemLookupCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can anyone who is more acquainted with SQL Server (2008 R2) help me fill in the blanks here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply rownumber on grouped results.

```
WITH cteresults AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Max(i.id) AS ID, 
        i.itemlookupcode, 
        Max(Cast(i.notes AS VARCHAR(max))) AS Notes, 
        Max(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), i.price, 1)) AS Price, 
        Max(i.picturename) AS PictureName 
    FROM   item AS i 
        LEFT JOIN nitroasl_pamtable AS n ON i.id = n.itemid 
    WHERE  ( i.id LIKE '%hdmi%' 
            OR i.itemlookupcode LIKE '%hdmi%' 
            OR i.notes LIKE '%hdmi%' 
            OR i.description LIKE '%hdmi%' 
            OR i.extendeddescription LIKE '%hdmi%' 
            OR n.manufacturerpartnumber LIKE '%hdmi%' 
            OR n.pam_keywords LIKE '%hdmi%' ) 
        AND (i.webitem = 0 AND i.price > 0) 
    GROUP  BY i.itemlookupcode
) 
,ctepagination AS 
(
    SELECT *, Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY itemlookupcode) AS RowID 
    FROM   cteresults
) 

SELECT * 
FROM   ctepagination 
WHERE  rowid BETWEEN 1 AND 15
```

This should work without CTE. But, not sure if it solves your problem stated in comment.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT *, Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY itemlookupcode) AS RowID from
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT Max(i.id) AS ID, 
            i.itemlookupcode, 
            Max(Cast(i.notes AS VARCHAR(max))) AS Notes, 
            Max(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), i.price, 1)) AS Price, 
            Max(i.picturename) AS PictureName 
        FROM   item AS i 
            LEFT JOIN nitroasl_pamtable AS n ON i.id = n.itemid 
        WHERE  ( i.id LIKE '%hdmi%' 
                OR i.itemlookupcode LIKE '%hdmi%' 
                OR i.notes LIKE '%hdmi%' 
                OR i.description LIKE '%hdmi%' 
                OR i.extendeddescription LIKE '%hdmi%' 
                OR n.manufacturerpartnumber LIKE '%hdmi%' 
                OR n.pam_keywords LIKE '%hdmi%' ) 
            AND (i.webitem = 0 AND i.price > 0) 
        GROUP  BY i.itemlookupcode
    ) t1
) t2
WHERE  rowid BETWEEN 1 AND 15
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I would not have figured this out. Seeing the query formatted this way also helps me understand what exactly is happening. Thank you!

Comment: So lo and behold, PHP's sqlsrv driver doesn't like the query. It succeeds, but returns no rows?... Is there possibly a different way to format this query that this driver may like a little better?

Comment: Dude, this works awesome! Thank you very, very much!